# Bulk Edit UserRoles for Acumatica Users

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I need to bulk update about 2000+ users in Acumatica (ie: Guest access users). I need to assign a new role to all of these user to support a new custom integration.

I am looking for a solution using either the Rest API or some sort of Excel bulk Import/Update that assigns the roles.

I have not had much luck working with UserRoles via the Rest API. I have only been able to download the users > user roles via a generic inquiry and ODATA. So far I have not found any documentation around this. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST Api is not really the best tool for this job. It doesn't contain an endpoint for Users (needs to be extended) and is a bit hard to use for complex logic. There isn't an Excel import mechanism either (outside import scenarios).

I would suggest to create a *Customization Plugin* for this task instead.
They can be created in Acumatica customization project editor with a new *CODE* file:
[image]

A customization plugin is a script that is executed when you publish the customization. I tested the following code which assign *Portal User* role to all guest users as an example.

```
using System;
using PX.Data;
using Customization;
using PX.SM;
using PX.EP;
using System.Linq;

namespace UpdateUserRoles
{
  public class UpdateUserRoles : CustomizationPlugin
  {
    public override void UpdateDatabase()
    {
      const string roleNameToAssign = "Portal User";

      AccessUsers accessUsers = PXGraph.CreateInstance<AccessUsers>();

      // For each users in the system
      foreach (Users user in accessUsers.UserList.Select())
      {
        // Modify only guest users
        if (user.Guest != true)
          continue;

        try
        {
          // Set current user
          accessUsers.UserList.Current = user;

          // Assign role
          EPLoginTypeAllowsRole role = (EPLoginTypeAllowsRole)accessUsers.AllowedRoles.Select().RowCast<EPLoginTypeAllowsRole>()
            .Where(x => x.Rolename.Contains(roleNameToAssign)).FirstOrDefault();

          role.Selected = true;
          accessUsers.AllowedRoles.Update(role);
          WriteLog("User " + user.Username + " updated.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          WriteLog("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
      }

      accessUsers.Save.Press();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I really don't have access to write any internal Acumatica customizations (another 3rd party vendor handles that). I am working on extraction of entity data (for an online eCommerce site). However, I will try this in my sandbox. If it works, I can run it up the chain for approval in production. Thank you again!

Comment: Right, access to an Acumatica website (localhost instance works) is required to create a customization. And you need to login with a Acumatica user that has Customizer user role (admin for localhost works). If you need help tweaking the customization plugin code you can post follow-up question on stack overflow.